# Shimano new shifters needed to replace 105 10speeds

Tags: gears, shifter, replacement

My right shifter has completely broken and I need to buy new shifters.

The current setup is a 10-speed system using 105's.  I appreciate that the new 105's come in an 11-speed option only.

The question is, what is my next best option?  I was going to buy a pair of Tiagra 4700's 10 speed, but I have heard that these are not compatible?

Which Tiagra shifters would be compatible with my existing 10-speed groupset?

Cheers!
S

Answer (score 1):

The ST-R4600 is a Tiagra model of shifter that is 10 speed but follows the the engineering of all Shimano 7, 8, 9, and 10 speed road shifter/derailleur's having a cable actuation ratio of 1.7:1 (derailleur) and the shifter pulls the necessary amount of cable.  With the release of Tiagra 4700, the shift actuation changed to be like 11 speed road despite remaining a 10 speed group set. It's generally felt that Tiagra 4700 components are only compatible with other 4700 parts.
A newer model of shifter for 10 speeds is ST-R460. It may be easier to acquire this 10 speed shifter as the 4600 is out of production and used or NOS is the likeliest options to get one of those. You only need the right shifter as left shifters are the same

Comment: The same as what?

Comment: In some cases, people might make cable pull adapters, but this might only be marginally cheaper than getting a used or even new rear derailleur. It seems like Jtek's Shiftmate 5 takes Tiagra 4700 shifters and a Shimano 11s MTB RD, but they have no solution for Tiagra 4700 shifters and an older 10s road RD. http://www.jtekengineering.com/shiftmate/shiftmate-compatibility-charts-choices/

Comment: @Vladimir F Left front shifters have such similar cable pulls (Cable pull specs for Shimano front shifters and their derailleur is dearth), that the 105, presumably 10 speed in this situation, will function the same whether marketed as 10 or 11 speed. Specifically what I meant by "the same" here, is whether Tiagra 4600 or 4700 or if a 105, the front shifters will all function similarly enough that they're interchangable.

Comment: However, there was a recent change of the front derailleurs cable pulls.  Across all Shimano models AFAIK. The new ones are not compatible with the older ones.

Comment: @Vladimir F While I haven't had occasion to try out more than an 11 speed rear drivetrain, I haven't had any problems with new XTR front derailleurs (FD-M9020) combined with 10 speed XT (M780) and XTR (M980) front shifters.  On the road side Ultegra (R8000) STI's work the Ultegra 6800 front der normally though they are both 11 speed and I expect that combo to work.  A change here wouldn't surprise me but I've yet to see a hiccup in the systems I've put together

Answer (score 1):

Any 10 speed Shimano <s>and SRAM</s> road bike shifter should be compatible, except for the Tiagra 4700 which has a different cable pull ratio. Edit: As Pisco points out in the comments, 10 speed GRX (and potentially future 10 speed groupsets) uses this new pull ratio as well.

You could try to find used Tiagra 4600 or Shimano 105 5700 shifters.

You could go for the Tiagra 4700 shifters and also replace the rear derailleur for a Tiagra 4700.

If your cassette, derailleurs and chain are worn down you could replace all of it and upgrade the whole drivetrain to Shimano 105 7000.

Comment: 10 speed GRX also uses the new 10 speed cable pull. Any Shimano legacy 10 speed road shifter, like 4600, should work, but we probably should note that 4700 isn’t a unique cable pull, it’s what they’re doing on new road 10 speed systems going forward.

Comment: SRAM road has no cross-compatibility with Shimano.